# CodeIgniter not catching DB errors while using PDO as driver

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.3, and I'm using the active record class with PDO as my database driver.

I came across an issue where CodeIgniter isn't reporting errors with incorrect update statements.  I can write a query which clearly violates duplicate keys or has incorrect column names, but CodeIgniter gives no error whatsoever with:

```
echo $this->db->_error_message(); //returns nothing
echo $this->db->_error_number();  //returns '0000'
```

However, as soon as I change over to using `MySQL` as the driver, I receive error messages.

I've even tried `$this->db->query(.... //violating statement` to bypass the active record class with no luck and more errors.

I have `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;`.

Am I out of luck using PDO, or are there some additional config settings that need to be changed when using PDO with CodeIgniter?

Comment: I use PDO as my driver and CI is showing me errors. I am testing on the development branch. There are no additional PDO settings. It might have been a bug in CI that has been fixed.

Comment: In my case, I don't get error in `PDOException`, but `_error_message()` and `_error_number()` works. but, if no rows are returned, FETCHALL won't work. Codeigniter PDO has serious problem.

Comment: I have also seen the fetchAll() method error when trying configure CodeIgniter to use 'pdo'. I'm not yet sure what's causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the PDO driver, you can see that the PDO connection is done with `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` which does not throw out any errors.

In general you want PDO to throw exceptions, in which case you pass the below with the connection options.

```
array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);
```

If you want to use PDO, use PDO direct. PDO is a good abstraction layer. If you are going to be using the CI DB Driver anyway, I don't see any real advantages of selecting this over mysql or vice-versa, because you will be writing your queries the CI way regardless.